# JS menu functions go to same page <a href=samepage.php> BUT both functions are called even though DOM elements are cleared

Tags: javascript, php

I have been struggling with this forever and.. it seems like it should be super easy. The goal is to group different functions under different pages, i.e. customer functions like create/read/update/delete should be on customers.php. I have tried SOOOO many ways, studied the cases on stackoverflow and yes, **@u_mulder I've tried the event listener**, **I’ve tried to set the page in my js function** using window.location.replace (assign, you name it) **as well as in php** and more. But I was unable to get any of those to work.  And NO, my question was NOT answered at the link you reference. Maybe it is just my inexperience, however, I do not see how that answer helps me when I need to link to .   does not get me to customers.php.  The **menus are** in a file located **here ../include/adminheader.php**. In my situation I need to know how this would work where **I do not simply have a '#' where the page link goes**. The person who answered my question helped a tremendous amount and allowed me to move forward on a problem that has blocked me for more than 2 months. Believe me I did not go lightly to stackoverflow with my question. Here my original question continues:: .. but I’ll just stick with the penultimate iteration here.  I have an HTML document header in a php include file that contains my menus. A submenu of ‘View’ contains options ‘All Customers’ and Single Customer’. These should both take the user to customers.php. Code to follow. No matter which menu item I click on both functions are called.

Menu Syntax contained in include/adminheader.php:

```
    <ul><a href="#">View</a>
       <li><a id="allCustomers" href="customers.php" >All Customers</a></li>
       <li><a id="singleCustomer" href="customers.php" >Single Customer</a></li>
    </li>
```

On the page customers.php at the bottom of the page I have:

```
<script>
var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
var search = document.getElementById("search");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var outputTable = document.getElementById("table"); 

document.getElementById("allCustomers").onclick = getCustomers();
document.getElementById("singleCustomer").onclick = viewCustomer();
</script>
```

Here are the javascript functions in my external javascript file located in scripts/adminjs.js

```
function getCustomers() {
    
    document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = "";
    grid.className = "grid_4cols";
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", "../controller/admincontroller.php?getCustomers=all", true);
    ajax.send();    
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {           
            var arr = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
            var result = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
                result += "<form action='../controller/admincontroller.php' method='POST' >";
                result += "<input type='hidden' id='id' name='id' value ='" + arr[i]['ID'] + "'>" ;
                result += "<input type='text' name='fname' value='" + arr[i]['fname'] + "'>" ;
                result += "<input type='text' name='lname' value='" + arr[i]['lname'] + "'>";
                result += "<input type='text' name='email' value='" + arr[i]['email'] + "'>";
                result += "<input type='submit' name='selectCustomer' value='Select' ></form>";
            }
            
            grid.innerHTML = result;

        }
    };
}

function viewCustomer() {
    document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = "";
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", "../controller/admincontroller.php?viewCustomer=all", true);
    ajax.send();    
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {           
            var arr = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
            var i = 0;
            
            if (!arr[i]['landline'] ) { 
                    arr[i]['landline'] = "";
                    }
            
                var table = "<table><tr><td class='th'>First Name:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['fname'] + "</td>";
                table += "<td class='th'>Last Name:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['lname'] + "</td></tr>";
                table += "<tr><td class='th'>Cell Number:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['phone'];
                table += "</td><td class='th'>Landline:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['landline'];
                table += "</td><td class='th'>Email:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['email'];
                table += "</td></tr><tr><td class='th'>Street:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['street'];
                table += "</td><td class='th'>City:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['city'];
                table += "</td><td class='th'>Zip:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['zip'];
                if (!arr[i]['animal_type']) {
                    table += "</td></tr><tr><td class='th'>Type of Animal:</td><td class='td'>' '";
                    table += "</td><td class='th'>Name:</td><td class='td'>' '";
                    table += "</td><td class='th'>Breed:</td><td class='td'> </td></tr>";
                }
                if (arr[i]['animal_type']) {
                    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
                        table += "</td></tr><tr><td class='th'>Type of Animal:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['animal_type'];
                        table += "</td><td class='th'>Name:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['name'];
                        table += "</td><td class='th'>Breed:</td><td class='td'>" + arr[i]['breed'] + "</td></tr>";
                    }
                }
                
                    table += "</table>"
                    outputTable.innerHTML = table +  
                    "<select onChange='window.location.href=this.value'><option selected disabled>I want to update..</option>" +
                    "<option value='updatecustomer.php'>Update Contact Info</option>" +
                    "<option value='updateanimals.php'> Update My Animals</option></select>";
        }
    };
}
```

Thanks for your help.

These functions work beautifully when I use a different php page for each function but that's now how this should work. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `document.getElementById("allCustomers").onclick = getCustomers()` should be `document.getElementById("allCustomers").onclick = getCustomers` - and the same with the other one. You don't want to call the function on page load, just to pass the function to the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: OK, thanks, I feel like I might be getting closer -- I had no idea about not putting the parens after the function. It appears that the function displays and then goes away. Is there somewhere I should put return false or something?

Comment: Inside both functions add `event.preventDefault();` to stop link normal behaviour.

Comment: OMG I am SO SO SO (infinity) happy. It works! Thank you both Triby and Robin. Much gratitude to you both. Upvotes and Accepting answer.. except somehow am unable to accept @RobinZigmond 's answer now. Help on that is appreciated while I look for an answer mysefl.

Comment: It's because it's not an answer but a comment, and comments can't be accepted

Comment: Wow that's too bad because it totally answered my question.